# How to covert to a list a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**We have a datataframe: df_1**

```
CODE    DESCRIPTION                           COUNT     DEVICES_ID
00      Electrical surges                       21      SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13, SAT15 
01      Overloading                              1      SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13 
02      Power sags and dips                     12      SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11 
03      A junction box that is uncovered         2      SAT1, SAT3, SAT5 
04      Switches of light not working            1      SAT1, SAT3 
05      Flickering light                         4      SAT31, SAT33, SAT35, SAT41, SAT43 
06      Tripping circuit breaker                 5      SAT31, SAT33, SAT35, SAT41 
07      Less outlets                            20      SAT31, SAT33, SAT35 
08      Electric shocks                         21      SAT31, SAT33 
09      Frequent burning out of light bulbs     22      SAT31 
10      Overcircuited panel                     12      SAT31, SAT33, SAT35, SAT41, SAT43, SAT45
```

**We want to obtain a dataframe: df_2**

```
CODE    DESCRIPTION                           COUNT     DEVICES_ID
00      Electrical surges                       21      [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13, SAT15] 
01      Overloading                              1      [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13] 
02      Power sags and dips                     12      [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11] 
03      A junction box that is uncovered         2      [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5] 
04      Switches of light not working            1      [SAT1, SAT3] 
05      Flickering light                         4      [SAT31, SAT33, SAT35, SAT41, SAT43] 
06      Tripping circuit breaker                 5      [SAT31, SAT33, SAT35, SAT41] 
07      Less outlets                            20      [SAT31, SAT33, SAT35]
08      Electric shocks                         21      [SAT31, SAT33]
09      Frequent burning out of light bulbs     22      [SAT31]
10      Overcircuited panel                     12      [SAT31, SAT33, SAT35, SAT41, SAT43, SAT45]
```

How to do in pandas dataframe

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: Hi. The solution is fine. Thanks. The problem is that  we need to obtain as result:

Comment: 0     ['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5', 'SAT11', 'SAT13', 'SAT15']
1     ['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5', 'SAT11', 'SAT13']
2     ...

Comment: Do you thin nested lists like `'L = df['DEVICES_ID'].str.split(', ').tolist()` ?

Comment: No. What we want to obtain is that each value contained in the arrays in column df_2 ['DEVICE_ID'] is enclosed in quotes, for example: ['value1', 'value2' ..., 'valueN']

Comment: What is reason for it? There are `''`, only not displayed. Check `print (df['DEVICES_ID'].iat[0])`

Comment: You're right. The quotes are there, only that at the beginning and end of the array of each row in column df_2 ['DEVICE_ID'] but the values ​​within the array are not in quotes. Each element / value of the array is a character string, so it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: hmm, are you sure you need it? Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['DEVICES_ID'] = df['DEVICES_ID'].str.split(', ')
```

--

EDIT: `''` are not displayed, by default, you can see them if check first list:

```
df['DEVICES_ID1'] = df['DEVICES_ID'].str.split(', ')
print (df['DEVICES_ID1'].iat[0])
['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5', 'SAT11', 'SAT13', 'SAT15']
```

If need add another `''` it is possible, but it means there are 2 times `"'`:

```
def f(s1):
    return "'{}'".format(s1)

df['DEVICES_ID2'] = df['DEVICES_ID'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: [f(y) for y in x])

print (df['DEVICES_ID2'].iat[0])
["'SAT1'", "'SAT3'", "'SAT5'", "'SAT11'", "'SAT13'", "'SAT15'"]
```

Output of splitted columns:

```
print (df)
   CODE                       DESCRIPTION  COUNT  \
0     0                 Electrical surges     21   
1     1                       Overloading      1   
2     2               Power sags and dips     12   
3     3  A junction box that is uncovered      2   

                              DEVICES_ID  \
0  SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13, SAT15   
1         SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13   
2                SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11   
3                       SAT1, SAT3, SAT5   

                               DEVICES_ID1  \
0  [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13, SAT15]   
1         [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11, SAT13]   
2                [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5, SAT11]   
3                       [SAT1, SAT3, SAT5]   

                                         DEVICES_ID2  
0  ['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5', 'SAT11', 'SAT13', 'SA...  
1         ['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5', 'SAT11', 'SAT13']  
2                  ['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5', 'SAT11']  
3                           ['SAT1', 'SAT3', 'SAT5']
```

---

Comment: The solution is perfect and it works with the sample data. I don't want to abuse your patience; but I want to show you an exercise where only the sample data changes, the solution / procedure does not change and the result is not the same. Could you help me understand why?

Comment: DEVICES_ID
000049668192,000049083092,000049239900,000049304492,000049200300,000049066092
000049089310
000049239900,000049196700,000049387200
000049150097,000049015792
000049768051,000049768051,000049768051,000049768051
000049768051,000049768051,000049768051,000049768051
000049347300
000049089310

Comment: ds1['DEVICES_ID'] = ds1['DEVICES_ID'].str.split(', ')

Comment: [000049668192,000049083092,000049239900,000049...
1                                       [000049089310]
2             [000049239900,000049196700,000049387200]
3                          [000049150097,000049015792]
4    [000049768051,000049768051,000049768051,000049...
5    [000049768051,000049768051,000049768051,000049...
6                                       [000049347300]
7                                       [000049089310]

Comment: print(ds1['DEVICES_ID'].iat[0])

Comment: ['000049668192,000049083092,000049239900,000049304492,000049200300,000049066092]